# How to get string between two strings when there are escaping characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get string between two strings and it works like this:

```
if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf("[CUSTOMTAG]") >= 0) {
      _data = /\[CUSTOMTAG](.*?)\[\/CUSTOMTAG]/g.exec(text);
      if (_data[1] && _data[1].length > 0) {
        const data = _data[1];
      }
    }
```

But I have problem when string between contains something like:

```
[CUSTOMTAG]this is some
[/ru ugly content here[/CUSTOMTAG]
```

I am getting exception here `Cannot read property '1' of null` because parsing fail.
How I can ignore excaping characters between?

Comment: [Did you check the singleline flag?](https://regex101.com/r/MWLt9S/1) or you can just use [`\[CUSTOMTAG]([\s\S]*?)\[\/CUSTOMTAG]`](https://regex101.com/r/MWLt9S/2)

Comment: Yep, your issue is probably not about escaping characters (as `/` is not an escaping one).

Comment: I replaced `(.*?)` with `([\s\S]*?)` now it works. But can you explain me difference please? @Potatoツ

Comment: `.` does not match newlines, by default. To make the `.` match a newline, you will have to use the singleline modifier - `s`. Or, if you cannot use singleline modifier, you can just replace `.` with something which matches everything, even the newlines. For that, I used `[\s\S]` i.e, any character which is either a white-space or a non-whitespace - Every character in the universe will be matched by this. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant but works. You may need to make some adjustments but it's an alternative:

```js
var input = `[CUSTOMTAG]this is some [/ru ugly content here[/CUSTOMTAG] [CUSTOMTAG]test2[/CUSTOMTAG]`;
var startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0, results = [];
while ((endIndex = input.indexOf("[/CUSTOMTAG]", endIndex)) >= 0 && (startIndex = input.indexOf("[CUSTOMTAG]", startIndex)) >= 0) {
 results.push(input.substring(startIndex + "[CUSTOMTAG]".length, endIndex));
 
 endIndex += "[/CUSTOMTAG]".length;
 startIndex += "[CUSTOMTAG]".length;
}
console.log(results);
```